# Can I set defaults value for two columns in a table sql in one command?

Tags: sql-server

Can I set default value for two columns in an table in sql

I tried below code

```
 alter table tbl_LaborMoney add constraint defaulZero 
       default 0 for "Total Paid Amount","Total Balance Amount"
```

But I got error:

```
Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The definition for column 'Total Balance Amount' must include a data type.
```

How would do that ?

Comment: You will have to write two alter statements and separate the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to define 2 constraints in a single `Alter Table`, but you'll need to give the second constraint a different name, and repeat the constraint syntax, viz:

```
alter table tbl_LaborMoney 
  add constraint defaultZero default 0 for "Total Paid Amount", 
      constraint defaultZero2 default 0 for "Total Balance Amount";
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb3c9/2)